# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: sitecore-commerce, azure, arm-template

I was installed `Sitecore XC 9.2.0` Scaled using the `ARM template`. After successful installation, when I am trying to open the`BizFX web app`, getting this error.

Most probably getting this error because of `.NET Core`. When I have checked the runtime stack, It was `.NET 4.7` and after changing this to `.NET Core`, no changes are there in the output.

[image]

Comment: The actual error might be logged in event log. In azure portal you can go to the SI webapp -> Diagnose and solve problems -> diagnostic tools -> application event logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one has been solved by putting the right license file in the identity server.